# getting data from a file and putting it into an array

Tags: python, arrays, file

```
with open('rules_test1Fold0w4_sample00ll1.dat') as fileobj:
    lines = list(fileobj)
actualrules=''
for index in sortrule:
    print lines[index]
```

I have this piece of code which prints out certain lines of a .dat file, however what i want to do is have each line to be an element in an array.
So for example if my file had this in

```
`'Once upon a time there was a young
  chap of the name of Peter he had a
  great friend called Claus'`
```

The array would be `[Once upon a time there was a young,chap of the name of Peter he had a,great friend called Claus]`

Comment: The code you posted does the thing you ask for. Do you have a question?

Comment: I guess you answered your own question

Comment: It prints the lines out, it doesn't put it into an array

Comment: Yes, it does put them in an array. It puts them in `lines`.

Comment: Or, are you wanting that only the lines selected by `sortrule` be put into the array?

Comment: Yeah I just want the lines selected by `sortrule` in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
with open('rules_test1Fold0w4_sample00ll1.dat') as fileobj:
    lines = fileobj.readlines()
actualrules=''
for index in sortrule:
    print lines[index]
```

That would give you a list of lines separated by \n

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted puts the lines of your input file into a `list`.

```
>>> with open('/etc/passwd') as fileobj:
...   lines = list(fileobj)
... 
>>> type(lines)
<type 'list'>
>>> lines[0]
'root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n'
>>>
```

Additionally, the code you posted has sort of a selection filter applied to it, printing out the lines specified in `sortrule`. If you want to have *those* lines stored in a `list`, try a list comprehension:

```
selected_lines = [lines[index] for index in sortrule]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you only need a one dimensional array, so a list is sufficient enough. And your code already stores each line into the list variable lines.